# Particle edit mode invisible geometry

Tags: particles, physics, hair

In particle edit mode when combing hairs,I find that some areas have collision "the guides can't be at that place" while there is nothing there.I don't know what is the cause.
[image]

Comment: The file :[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=w11DBEEe" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/w11DBEEe/)

Answer (score 0):

It should have something to do with face normal.Add a solidify modifier, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's the "deflect emitter" checkbox, if turned on it tries to deflect the particle curves from the emitter in with a very rough distance scale (for example turning it down to 1mm doesn't actually work, it remains somewhere around a few centis)

[image]